# Are ARM cortex-R watchpoints accessible via CP14 interface

Tags: debugging, arm

On an ARM v7 Cortex-R4 chip, is there any way to access DBGWCR and DBGWVR using the mrc instruction, the mcr instruction and the CP14 interface? I cannot find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/Bcgcbfif.html) lists the six CP14 accessible registers. They are enough to locate the memory mapped interface to the remaining debug registers, DBGDSAR  and DBGDRAR being the key ones.

The memory mapped interface *ought* to be accessible from the core in any implementation, but there are no hard guarantees.